# ECS: How do I instantiate Entities from a file of positions

Tags: unity, entity-component-system, unity-dots

I am quite new to Unity ECS and am trying to instantiate a few thousand entities based on positions stored in a .csv file. The file format can of course change, if that helps. My problem is to import the data to Unity, best case baking the positions in an array, as they will not change during using the application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we assume that you already know how to spawn entities in general, and what we actually need to explain is how to load positions from a file and store them in a data-structure that's performant to access for an ECS System?

Comment: Yes! I am able to spawn entities at random positions, manipulate them etc.